# Getting the sum of an arraylist - java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arraylist of strings in which the last row of the csv file is random numbers. I need to sum all of them together and return it as long, but cant figure out how to do so because right now it is saying `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field randomNumber` which I do not want to make randomNumber static because it then messes up gathering the randomNumbers from the data file.

 **My data is** 
 
andrew,Comma,comma1aj,83559,
Andrew,Karpenter,karpe1aj,966796,15.7
Brandon,Turnip,turni1bw,715855,
Brenda,Miso,miso1b,747747,
Chris,Shoe,shie1c,123784,
David,Cool,Cool1d,200100,
Django,,uncha1d,830700,
Erik,Tata,,400500,
Jakob,Doolittle,dooli1j,555777,
Thomas,Jefferson,jeff1t,951753,
Kaya,Coffee,coffee1k,789456,
Owen,Wilson,wilso1o,456123,
Test,student,seeli1p_s,,
,demo,demo1s,58578,

My main class is

```
public class Main {
static ArrayList<Student> Students = new ArrayList<Student>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String fileLocation = getFile();
    File file = new File(fileLocation);
    while(!file.exists()) {
        fileLocation = getFile();
    }

    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(new File(fileLocation));
    while (scnr.hasNextLine()) {
        String text = scnr.nextLine();
        //System.out.println("text = " + text);
        String[] data = text.split(",");
        if(data.length !=4 || data[0].isEmpty() || data[1].isEmpty() || data[2].isEmpty()) {
            continue;
        }
        Students.add(new Student(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]));
    }

    for (Student tmp : Students) {
        System.out.println(tmp);
    }

    Student.getSum();

}

public static String getFile() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter file location: ");
    String fileLocation = reader.readLine();
    //System.out.println(fileLocation);
    return fileLocation;
}
}
```

My student class is

```
public class Student {
public String fName = "";
public String lName = "";
public String logonID = "";
public String randomNumber = "";

public Student (String fName, String lName, String logonID, String randomNumber) {
    this.setName(fName, lName);
    this.setID(logonID);
    this.setNumber(randomNumber);
}

public Student() {
    fName = "";
    lName = "";
    logonID = "";
    randomNumber = "";
}

public void setName(String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.fName = firstName;
    this.lName = lastName;
}

public void setID(String studentID) {
    this.logonID = studentID;
    logonID.toLowerCase();
}

public void setNumber(String randomNumber) {
    this.randomNumber = randomNumber;
}

public static long getSum() {
    long sum = 0;
    sum = Long.parseLong(randomNumber);
    return sum;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.fName + " " + this.lName;
}

}
```

Comment: You know, you're actually supposed to do some of your *own* homework. If you keep dumping your assignments here, you'll never learn how to debug or how to code.

Comment: `getSum` can't be `static`, it makes no sense.  Instead, loop over the `Students` list

Comment: You may want to review cmu policy [15-150](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~./15150/policy.html) (and the more general [link](https://www.cmu.edu/policies/student-and-student-life/academic-integrity.html) provided there).